# Is there a distribution defaulting to GNOME 3 Classic Mode?

Tags: linux-distributions, gnome3

For some reason, Ubuntu has defaulted to the Unity desktop, a desktop which really makes sense on a tablet.

Does anyone know if there is a GNOME 3 distribution based/defaulting to GNOME 3 classic mode?  So basically, it would look similar to GNOME 2, but runs GNOME 3 without Unity or GNOME 3 Shell.

Comment: You could just install GNOME3 on Ubuntu. Just because it isn't the default doesn't mean you can't use it. Would you rebuild your entire house because you didn't like the look of the front door?

Comment: But Ubuntu already has Gnome3 installed.

Comment: Even if you would switch to the classic desktop on Ubuntu, the developer team concentrates on the Unity "experience".

Comment: Yes, which is why I am asking if anyone knows of a distribution which will concentrate on gnome3-classic or classic mode.  Plus sounds like the fallback mode has been removed totally from Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What comes close to the classic Gnome 2 feeling is [Linux Mint 12 RC](http://linuxmint.com)
But there's no real alternative to the Gnome Shell GUI.

Comment: Looks like Mint 12 is going to use Mate, a gnome2 fork, which I mentioned below.  I'll  have to accept your answer in that case!  Thanks.

Comment: Plus Linux Mint allows you to turn everything off giving you a basic gnome3 desktop!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org) comes with Gnome3, without Unity, that is.
Expect [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/en/) do the same. (It'll be released in 2 days.)

Comment: Doesn't Fedora come with Gnome3 + Gnome3-shell?  I was after a distro which does Gnome3 + the Gnome3-classic-shell, or classic mode by default.

Comment: It runs the classic Gnome3 as far as I know, and as much as I remember. Try it in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found so far:

[MATE Desktop Environment](https://github.com/Perberos/Mate-Desktop-Environment), a non-intuitive and unattractive desktop for users, using traditional computing desktop metaphor. Also known as the GNOME2 fork.

Answer (score 0):

Trisquel GNU/Linux is a good alternative. It is a 100% pure free OS.
You may find it here http://trisquel.info

It provides customized version of gnome3 fall back model and provide an experience like customized gnome 2. And we can customize it like gnome 2

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide a link for reference.